# Maps for both Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, maps

Anyone know maps API that can be implemented for both Android and iOS, except Google Maps and Bing Maps?

Comment: Use web view in both, Thats the only common option. https://developers.google.com/maps/ How about, Bing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx

Comment: seems it still uses Google Maps API, i don't want to use that API..Please don't ask why :)

Comment: I'm interested with Bing but still looking for any other options :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OpenStreetMap's API to render your own, which is more involved than google maps but will work on both.

http://www.openstreetmap.org/

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API